When constructing a HashSet, does the capacity argument take the load factor into account?
The .NET API gives the following remarks for the HashSet<T>(Int32) constructor:

Since resizes are relatively expensive (require rehashing), this attempts to minimize the need to resize by setting the initial capacity based on the value of the capacity [argument].

The phrase based on the value gives me faith that the constructor does something smarter than simply setting the underlying array capacity to capacity. But will I be guaranteed to be able to add capacity items to the set with no resize?
The underlying load factor is of course an implementation detail. I checked if it is exposed by any API method, and it apparently isn't. So hopefully .NET is using its knowledge of the load factor the way I want it to in this constructor.

The implementation can be seen on GitHub by clicking the source link in the docs.
After skipping through a few method calls, and a guard where it throws if capacity < 1, we get to the interesting part.
/// <summary>
/// Initializes buckets and slots arrays. Uses suggested capacity by finding next prime
/// greater than or equal to capacity.
/// </summary>
private int Initialize(int capacity) {
  int size = HashHelpers.GetPrime(capacity);

So, it does not directly use the load factor in the calculation, but using the next prime instead is still a pretty desirable implementation, as discussed here.

So it sounds like the array could be subject to resizing if capacity is prime, or nearly equal to its next prime, and I do add capacity elements to the set.

Yes, definitely. Unlike Java, which has a load factor of 0.75, my understanding is that in C# the default load factor is 1 --- it only grows when you try to add more elements than would fit in the current capacity, so generally it's just less of a consideration. They've opted for the prime-based approach (e.g. it grows to the smallest prime that's at least twice as big) to ensure that collisions remain down when growing

They don't mention load factors at all in the HashSet docs, and the way it's written it's just effectively hardcoded to 1 from what I can tell. In the HashTable docs, they do discuss it, with the following quote "The default load factor of 1.0 generally provides the best balance between speed and size."

But yeah, I completely agree --- if you had a prime capacity, and you then added capacity items to the set, it would immediantly grow.
